# Huge and long sql query delay the php session_start() until query ends

Tags: php, mysql

I got a cron that calls a php file and launches a huge SQL update on the database.

something like that :

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.a = (SELECT sum() FROM .... )
```

This query takes seconds to execute (maybe 20sec).

While the query is running, all the others scripts (from http or from cli)  are delayed. Actually these scripts hold on the session_start() function.

When the sql query ends, the other script (which were waiting on session_start() ) can run again (if they didn't reach the timeout) .

The session uses file system as save handler.

EDIT :

Better explained in main steps :

**I got 2 files**

File 1 : cron.php : is launched by a cron

1. sql connection
2. huge sql queries

cron.php :

```
<?php
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query('UPDATE t1 SET t1.a=(SELECT SUM(t2.a) FROM t2  WHERE "some where clauses")');
mysql_query('UPDATE t1 SET t1.b=(SELECT SUM(t2.b) FROM t2  WHERE "some where clauses")');
mysql_query('UPDATE t3 SET t3.c=(SELECT SUM(t2.b) FROM t2  WHERE "some where clauses")');
```

File 2 : index.php : http reachable

1. session_start()
2. some codes

index.php:

```
<?php

// index.php
echo "SESSION STARTING";
session_start();
echo "SESSION STARTED";
```

**What happens :**

1. a cron launches `php cron.php`
2. someone browses the website he goes to index.php
3. apache launches `index.php`
4. index.php holds on `session_start()`
5. the cron job ends
6. `index.php` can run normally

In alternative to the 6. if the script is too much long, then i can see the following lines in the logs :

```
Premature end of script headers
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
```

That means that the script spent 40 second trying to read the session file

The question is what could be the link between mysql query and the session start and what could delay the session_start()  ?

The server runs on Debian 7.

Comment: OK. But what is the question?

Comment: Updated : The question is what could be the link between mysql query and the session start and what could delay the session_start() ?

Comment: Th delay is badly written code. Why are SQL queries running before things like session_start() are called.

Comment: Updated. I dont use session start in the cron

Comment: I think you should provide some more code in order to examine if there is some specific condition that could lead to that behavior.

Comment: Done, i put  what is running (exept for the sql queries)

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to optimize those queries? At first glance, they look like they're correlated, which is bad for performance.

Comment: Yea DCoder i'm considering to optimise it. But the fact is that it locks the session_start, and even if i optimize the query, a problem (or a human mistake) lives somewhere on the server about the session_start !

Comment: I dont think a seession_start() problem, try removing this from your index.php file. I guess it happens because your tables are locked as the index.php does some DB operations

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is you are using MyISAM tables?

Those are non-transactionnal and if MySQL has to acquire a lock (say for an update operation) -- the entire table is locked, and so, blocking other queries on that table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

---

As of blocking on `session_start()` this would be coherent with that explanation *iif* you store your sessions in the database. And somehow the cronjob has to access the corresponding table too (does it open a session by itself?).

Comment: Sylvain Leroux, yes these tables are using myisam. But why the script holds on session_start ? session handler is the file system and not the database, then the session_start doesnt care about locked table. Right ?